# ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Tags: sql, oracle, toad

I have the code below, and I receive the error: **ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected** at the fourth select (***). Does anyone know why?

I have searched the other posts and have not found my solution.

```
select plan_date as Week,
      plan_date+7 as "Week + 7",
      plan_date+14 as "Week + 14",
      plan_tower, 
      plan_rice_type, 
      plan_hours/100 as Plan_Count,

      (select count(*)
       from smart_rice_cooker rc
       where rc.tower = p.plan_tower and
             rc.rice_type = p.plan_rice_type and
             rc.status <> 'Cancelled' and
             rc.actual_fd_date between p.plan_start_date and p.plan_end_date
      ) as Delivered_FD_Count,

      (select count(*)
       from smart_rice_cooker rc
       where rc.tower = p.plan_tower and
             rc.rice_type = p.plan_rice_type and
             rc.status <> 'Cancelled' and
             rc.actual_fd_date is null and
             rc.target_fd_date between p.plan_start_date and p.plan_end_date
       ) as Target_FD_Count

       ***(select count(*)
       from smart_rice_cooker rc
       where rc.tower = p.plan_tower and
             rc.rice_type = p.plan_rice_type and
             rc.status <> 'Cancelled' and
             rc.actual_td_date between p.plan_start_date+7 and p.plan_end_date+7
      ) as Delivered_TD_Count,

      (select count(*)
       from smart_rice_cooker rc
       where rc.tower = p.plan_tower and
             rc.rice_type = p.plan_rice_type and
             rc.status <> 'Cancelled' and
             rc.actual_rt_date between p.plan_start_date+14 and p.plan_end_date+14
      ) as RT_Delivered_Count,

      (select count(*)
       from smart_rice_cooker rc
       where rc.tower = p.plan_tower and
             rc.rice_type = p.plan_rice_type and
             rc.status <> 'Cancelled' and
             rc.actual_rt_date is null and
             rc.target_rt_date between p.plan_start_date+14 and p.plan_end_date+14
       ) as RT_Target_Count

from smart_plan p
order by plan_tower, plan_rice_type, plan_date
```

Comment: There's a comma missing after `Target_FD_Count`, right before the inidcated error location.

Comment: Missing comma after Target_FD_Count

Comment: Thanks, must have just overlooked that

Answer (score 4):

There is no comma after `as Target_FD_Count`.  You need to add a comma there.

```
(select count(*)
   from smart_rice_cooker rc
   where rc.tower = p.plan_tower and
         rc.rice_type = p.plan_rice_type and
         rc.status <> 'Cancelled' and
         rc.actual_fd_date is null and
         rc.target_fd_date between p.plan_start_date and p.plan_end_date
   ) as Target_FD_Count, -- <-- Comma here

   (select count(*)
   from smart_rice_cooker rc
   where rc.tower = p.plan_tower and
         rc.rice_type = p.plan_rice_type and
         rc.status <> 'Cancelled' and
         rc.actual_td_date between p.plan_start_date+7 and p.plan_end_date+7
  ) as Delivered_TD_Count,
```

Comment: Thanks, I must have just overlooked that.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the comma after the alias Target_FD_Count. Generally when you spot this error, check the commas in your select.